# How to add tick to a custom radio using css?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have a simple custom radio and I want to add a ticky when clicked,

I tried below code :

```css
p.payment_module a {
 display: block;
 border: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
 border-radius: 0px;
 line-height: 23px;
 color: #000;
 position: relative;
 border: none !important;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-transform: initial;
 font-family: "futura-pt, sans-serif";
}

p.payment_module a span {
 color: #777;
 font-weight: normal !important;
}

p.payment_module a:after {
 content: '';
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: text-top;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 padding: 0px;
 left: -16px !important;
 top: 9px !important;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 50%;
}


p.payment_module a:before{
 content: '✔';
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #fff;
}
```

```html
<p class="payment_module">
 <a href="http://localhost:8080/index.php?fc=module&amp;module=bankwire&amp;controller=payment&amp;id_lang=1" title="Zapłać przelewem" class="button button-block payment-button">
  <img src="/modules/bankwire/bankwire.jpg" alt="Zapłać przelewem" width="86" height="49">
  Zapłać przelewem&nbsp;<span>(czas przetwarzania zamówienia będzie dłuższy)</span>
 </a>
</p>
```

My custom radio does not display the tick when I click , What am I missing in my code?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does clicked mean checked in your case? From html it seems click redirects to payment page, so there's no point to display tick. You would need actual radio input to make it work like https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `<a>` css, Please check below code:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius:50px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin:0;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  content: "✔";
  font-family: 'lucida grande';
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="payment_module">
 <input id="session1" name="radio-group" type="radio" />
 <label for="session1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/86/49/?random" alt="Zapłać przelewem" width="86" height="49">
  Zapłać przelewem&nbsp;<span>(czas przetwarzania zamówienia będzie dłuższy)</span>
  </label>
</p>
```